# How to enable USB debugging on a soft-bricked Huawei phone?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, adb, unbricking, huawei

Yesterday, i rooted my phone with KingRoot and downloaded a SoftKey Enabler because i wanted to play Uplink on my Huawei Y560 (a.k.a. Y5). The SoftKey Enabler edited the build.prop file. It restarted my Huawei Y5, but after it showed the Huawei logo, the screen flashed and turned dark. I panicked a bit, took out the battery and restarted into Recovery Mode with pressing Vol + Power. I formatted everything, cleared the cache, but it still didnt work. Then i found that i can fix it by using ADB, but it required USB debugging enabled, which i dont know how to make.

My goal is: To repair a soft-bricked Huawei Y560 (Y5) file so it can boot again. It has no USB debugging enabled, and the firmware on the official site is outdated. Please, somebody help me!

Comment: Yes, you can (may be actually) fix the device if you *precisely* know what you changed in build.prop or you've an original copy of it. If you don't then don't bother with USB debugging. Also, if you do not have a custom recovery, then there is no point in thinking about solving the issue using adb. You won't be granted shell access, let alone root access in stock recovery. // Flash the ROM.

Comment: If you already formatted everything (by which I assume you only mean `/data` and `/cache` otherwise you can't boot at all) and it won't boot, then you need to access the file using the recovery. Get hold of a custom recovery (TWRP or PhilZ should do the job, CWM does not always have a USB debugging feature) and edit that file. Even better: Get the original file or look for a backup (good apps do backups) and put that in place of your broken file. Last thing: Don't modify anything of the system without a backup (nandroid ie. full device backup).

Comment: With formatting i mean resetting to factory and clearing cache

Comment: @GiantTree How i can do that? I have a microsd, but the USB debugging is disabled and i can boot only in recovery mode

Comment: I don't know how to flash a custom recovery on Huawei devices, but it should involve `fastboot`AFAIK. You don't need to enable USB debugging in Android, the recovery is Android independent.

Comment: @GiantTree Where can i get that 'fastboot' thing? I downloaded the TWRP for Huawei Y5, what should i do next?

Comment: Again: I have no idea how to flash anything on Huawei devices. Check out xda threads on how to install/flash a custom recovery to your device.